# How to fix SendGrid CORS error from React Js application?

Tags: reactjs, cors, sendgrid

I have a react application and I am trying to send an email using SendGrid, I am using `@sendgrid/mail` to send an email.
But it shows this error when I sent an email and the email doesn't send.

I got this error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`

My code looks like this

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey("key");

const message = {
      to: "to email",
      from: "from email",
      subject: "subject",
      html: `
      <p><strong>Hello/strong></p>`,
    };

    Gmail
      .send(message)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Email Sent!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
      });
```

Please help to fix this!

Comment: Are you trying to execute this code on the client side? I would not recommend doing that as it means you would expose your API key.

Comment: Yes, I am executing it on the client side.

Comment: Ok let me check how can I achieve that with the keystone backend

Comment: Yes, that would be the better option then. I'll also submit an answer to this questions so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend doing that as it means you would expose your API key.

But there's an alternative if you say you don't want/need a backend. You can use [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets) to implement the code to send the SMS and [protect the Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/json-web-token) either with a JWT token or (for testing) basic auth.